# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osgeo' in virtualenvironment

Tags: python, installation, ogr, osgeo

As I am working in ubuntu. This works if I deactivate the virtual environment but after activating the environment I got the error saying no module named osgeo.

How do I install it?

```
from osgeo import ogr, osr
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I am able to solve this by installing libgdal-dev and pygdal (Virtualenv and setuptools friendly version of standard GDAL python bindings.)

```
sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev
```

In case not installed, install using aptitude

```
sudo aptitude install libgdal-dev
```

After that check GDAL version of your system,

```
gdalinfo --version
```

lets say you have GDAL version as

```
GDAL 2.2.3, released 2017/11/20
```

Then install pygdal of same version of GDAL

```
pip install pygdal==2.2.3.3
```

**Also I am able to install with single command**

```
pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/usr/include/gdal" GDAL==`gdal-config --version`
```