# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_gdal' in Ubuntu 20.04 and Python 3.8

Tags: python, gdal

I know that this has been asked multiple times, but I still arrive at the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_gdal'` error in my Ubuntu 20.04 workstation and with Python 3.8 under Anaconda. The following are suggestions that I have tried:

1. Install GDAL with `conda install -c conda-forge gdal` - it seemed to successfully install at first, but upon importing `osgeo` into Python, I get the `ModuleNotFoundError`;
2. Install GDAL through `pip` - this does not succeed in installing GDAL. I receive an error indicating that the wheel file cannot be built;
3. Install `pygdal` either through `pip` or `conda` (https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/356609/208986) - this has the same result as (1). I even downgraded my Python to 3.6 to install it through `conda`, but to no success;
4. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72413306/14081094 - I cannot successfully complete these steps due to GDAL not installing through `pip` (see 2);
5. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72887401/14081094, https://stackoverflow.com/a/41613466/14081094 - it was able to successfully install GDAL in Ubuntu 20.04, but unable to install GDAL in Python, again, through `pip` or `conda` (see 1 and 2);

Weirdly enough, I can import GDAL through the base environment of Anaconda with no errors (using any of the steps), however when I try to import it through a virtual environment, the error occurs.

Comment: Did you perhaps use `import gdal` instead of `from osgeo import gdal`?

Comment: I am importing GDAL through `from osgeo import gdal`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me on Windows with the commands copied from https://gist.github.com/ThomasG77/40a9f033131c9b49fe70b22a5f9c701a

```
conda create --name gdaltest python=3.8
conda activate gdaltest
conda install gdal libgdal

python
>>> from osgeo import gdal
>>> gdal.VersionInfo()
'3060200'
```

Article https://opensourceoptions.com/blog/how-to-install-gdal-with-anaconda/ has advice for troubleshooting.

**EDIT**

It may be necessary to install also krb5, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/440118

```
conda install krb5
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: I personally prefer to specify all required packages when creating the environment instead of afterwards, e.g. `conda create --name gdaltest python=3.8 gdal libgdal etc` as conda only has to 'solve' the environment once and you're less likely to get any inconsistent packages and have to upgrade/downgrade existing packages.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, but suffices for me on a Mac M1: pinning `gdal<3.6` in my Conda environment made things work for me again.

After some `CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-64 micromamba create --prefix ./venv -f conda_environment.yml` I then see `_gdal.py` exists:

```
ls -l ./venv/**/_gdal.py
-rw-rw-r--  2 arjan  staff  420 Sep  1  2021 ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/osgeo/_gdal.py
```

Without that pin, which in my project got me GDAL 3.6.x today (which is not the latest, probably due to a Python 3.8 dependency in my project), I got the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_gdal'` and no file `_gdal.py` exists then. That’s all I know; hoping it may help someone investigating for a proper solution if things suddenly break.

Answer (score 0):

This method works for me in python 3.11
First, download the appropriate .whl file (in my case GDAL-3.4.3-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl since I use python 3.11) from

[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal)

then, install the file from command prompt, as can be seen in

https://opensourceoptions.com/how-to-install-gdal-for-python-with-pip-on-windows/